Why is normality of residuals (homoskedasticity) "not needed" for OLS regression?
Recently there has been a barrage of posts on Twitter critiquing someone for stating that normality of residuals is a necessary assumption for OLS regression / the General Linear Model.
Posts include comments such as:
https://x.com/JamesBland_Econ/status/1852710578168459372

Just don't! So much of my econometrics class is spent un-doing common misconceptions
like this.
Normality of errors is not needed Heteroskedasticity is not a problem
for bias Multicollenearity is not a problem for bias

https://x.com/Josh_Merfeld/status/1852640894450860092

Normality is necessary only in very specific circumstances, usually
when sample size is small. People who think they must test normality
of the residuals (though the assumption is on the error term) make me
doubt their knowledge of statistics.

https://x.com/CamargoFelipe1/status/1852646653209067842

Normality of residuals isn't a key assumption for OLS.
Key assumptions about residuals for minimum variance linear estimators
via least squares according to the Gauss-Markov theorem are:

Stationarity (no trends)
No residual autocorrelation
Constant long run variance


https://x.com/YanndeMey/status/1852640245772120158

Can we please stop always suggesting that all things need to be
normally distributed in statistics, such as the residuals in a linear
model? For estimation, they only need to be iid. For inference we can
bring in normality for convenience, but there are alternatives.

https://x.com/arthur_spirling/status/1852688038008061975

It’s interesting reading these “tips” as a flashback to my own grad
stats classes. Ofc, nothing in Gauss-Markov requires normal errors.
But more broadly this stuff is a (at best) misguided concern for
almost everything we are actually trying to use the model for.

https://x.com/SouadH9/status/1852807926391640271

The only assumptions needed for interpreting the results of a linear
regressions models are ONLY :

i.i.d observations
no colinearity

All the rest (normality distribution of error terms, heteroscedascity
of variance, linear relationship between Y and X_n..etc) is WRONG.

Frankly, I am a little surprised at the backlash against the post. In my education, I always learned of normality of residuals as one of the key assumptions of the General Linear Model. Over time, my impression developed that violations of this assumption can be less of a concern, particularly at larger sample sizes. But I remain a bit confused by all of the backlash around suggesting that normality of residuals is an assumption of General Linear Model. Can someone provide insight or help explain?
Is normality of residuals not needed for OLS / General Linear Model? If so, why? And if it's not needed, why is it so commonly taught in statistics education as "fundamental" assumption of the linear model?
Furthermore, one thing that puzzles me is that in my early education, I often received the incorrect education that your outcome needs to be normally distributed for t-tests, ANOVA, and general linear model. In fact, it seems to be the case that it is normal distribution of residuals/errors. In reviewing the criticisms of normally distributed errors, what is actually necessary for general linear model? Is it basically only i.i.d observations?

Well, the burden of proof is the other way around. Depending on what (asymptotic) properties you want the OLS estimator to have, you can prove that it has all of them without assuming normality. Proofs can be found in most modern econometric textbooks. My own personal belief is that the normality assumption is pedagogically accessible (it is sufficient but not necessary) in methods courses in applied fields and is most often perpetuated there. And of course it is really handy in securing some finite sample properties, but not essential even there in many cases.

Many similar questions https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/395011/why-normality-assumption-in-linear-regression https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/641130/why-does-the-normality-assumption-not-affect-linear-regression-in-large-samples  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/152674/why-is-the-normality-of-residuals-barely-important-at-all-for-the-purpose-of-e https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/578454/understanding-the-assumptions-of-linear-regression-residuals-or-data-must-come ...

... https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/148803/how-does-linear-regression-use-the-normal-distribution

All those duplicate questions boil down to the OLS being valid even without normality and homoscedasticity, they are not necessary for the estimation method to 'work well'. However, certain aspects may be improved if the errors follow a normal distribution (and that is why sometimes normality is a necessary or desired property). For example, more efficient estimators might be possible, or inference about the outcome of the OLS regression requires knowledge of the distribution for good estimates of variability in the end result, etc.

The irony here is that (marginal) normality of the errors is not even adequate to insure the goodness of OLS. After all, the true marginal distribution of the errors can be normal even when Y is binary, and you shouldn't be using OLS in that case. The assumption concerns conditional, not marginal distributions. It is not needed to discuss the error distribution at all, since the assumption applies equivalently to both Y and the errors.

There's three distinct senses in which one can interpret a statement like "Normality is not needed for OLS", and correspondingly three distinct answers (albeit these distinct issues are often conflated, which is how many of the disagreements that happen can will arise). I think most of your quoted tweets relate to one in particular, but I don't want to address them specifically (except for a brief aside or two, where I largely agree with their conclusions, at least under the conditions they're taking as given) but to treat the title question on its merits.
The three senses in which normality might not be required when doing "OLS" are:

OLS taken literally: If you say "OLS" and mean what you say, you're literally just defining your loss function. Clearly if you have defined your loss already, assumptions don't really come into it after that; you're saying you want to estimate your parameters by optimizing a specific thing ... so you just optimize it. There might be room to quibble about whether it was a good choice of loss function for your purposes. For example, if you don't have near to homoskedasticity in the process you're sampling, the estimator may be inefficient. But it's your loss function to choose if that's what you decide you want, then fine.
This choice makes no assumption about how (or even whether) you'll carry out any additional inference after estimation. You are not required to use some particular inferential procedure if you do, the loss function choice for estimation doesn't really speak to your inferences, and you may well have some additional choices to make at that point.

Estimation: Let's imagine you didn't really mean to specify the loss function when you said "OLS", and you simply want to fit a (presumably*) linear model, $E(Y|X=x) = X\beta$. The question may then be "what's a good estimator to use in my circumstances?". If there's heteroskedasticity you will typically not want to ignore that.
It's important to be aware that to estimate $\beta$ using least squares does not require you to assume normality specifically (though it's most efficient there).
For example, there's the Gauss-Markov theorem, which says under some moderate conditions that least squares is the best linear unbiased estimator of the parameters. This means that among the unbiased linear estimators of $\beta$, given the conditions of the theorem, least squares is best in a particular sense. This is quite a nice result. You can also get standard errors of your estimates (given those conditions).
However, it does not imply that any linear estimator is necessarily very good, even when the conditions hold. That depends on the circumstances. Often it will be fine but that doesn't mean it's great in every possible situation.
My advice if you're wanting to invoke this result is at least to make sure the other conditions make sense, and to at least worry a little about whether a situation where a linear estimator might be relatively quite poor doesn't apply. If, for example, you're trying to work with extreme value distributions based off variables that are not themselves short-tailed, I wouldn't typically suggest linear estimators would be a good idea for most of those applications. More generally, if you may have very heavy tails, think very carefully about whether this (optimizing among linear estimators) makes sense. Further, the other assumptions more often tend not to apply in the same circumstances. A more plausible choice of model may solve all these issues together, rather than trying to rely on doing well with the class of linear estimators.

Inferential properties of tests and intervals: There is a situation where you do assume normality, in deriving the properties of inferential procedures such as the usual t and F tests, confidence intervals for $\beta$ and functions of $\beta$, and most especially for prediction intervals. If you don't assume normality but something else, you don't get t and F distributions for those test statistics under $H_0$.
So if you assumed it in deriving a t test or an F test, say, why say it might not matter?
Typically those assumptions are made when trying to guarantee that specific properties of their inferential procedures will hold, such as that the significance level is maintained when this or that null hypothesis is true, or that CIs have the desired coverage.
The question is, then, if you don't have normality, will those properties still be pretty close to being attained? (In short, how robust is this or that property to violations of that specific distributional assumption?)
For the usual tests and CIs (but not for PIs), under moderate conditions, those procedures tend to be robust (those specific properties you were trying to attain will very nearly hold) in sufficiently large samples. I note that some of your quotes point to other assumptions as typically being more important, and in many cases I'd tend to agree, given you have large samples. Sometimes "sufficiently large" to not worry so much about normality is actually fairly small, but sometimes it isn't. How large is large also depends on your willingness to tolerate approximation, how much it matters to you or your audience whether you might be off on one side rather than the other, especially if you're interested in a one-tailed test or a one sided interval, and so on.
Simulation can be a convenient tool for investigating the properties of your inference in a variety of circumstances you might be concerned about, but my advice is avoid falling into confirmation bias when doing so. In particular, I often see a strong tendency to only investigate particularly "nice" cases with simulation (e.g. to look at say the distribution of a  two sample t-statistic with exponential data at say $n=40$ and then  conclude that skewness is a non-issue even for one-sided, one sample t-tests at any sample size, with any skewed distribution). I don't think it's usually deliberate, but more a lack of imagination or understanding of what sorts of violations might matter, and what might be possible.


Now for some advice:
A. If you're in situation 3, and you do decide to use least squares regression, and you're concerned that non-normality might be an issue for properties of your inference like accuracy of significance levels, you don't have to use the usual procedures for tests, confidence intervals or even prediction intervals. Among other options, if you have a different parametric model for the random variation in the response, you can obtain effectively 'exact' inference with your chosen estimator; if you don't have a parametric model there's resampling tests and intervals for example (permutation and bootstrap procedures), which are approximate rather than small-sample-exact in the case of coefficient tests in multiple regression but can perform quite well though an overall test of the model vs a null model can be made exact with some simple assumptions. For simple regression you can do exact tests of the coefficient.
B. If you're in a situations where you're concerned that least squares estimation may be relatively inefficient even in larger samples, or that your tests may have low power, or your intervals may be unnecessarily wide, due to suspecting stronger departures from normality, you can make other, more suitable assumptions and derive efficient estimators, efficient tests and intervals with suitable properties.  (You may also improve the more basic properties like significance level and coverage, particularly in smaller samples.)
C. Generally speaking, avoid using the same data to choose your model as you do to estimate it and perform inference on it. There are several ways you can go about making reasonable model choices before you even collect data, but even if that's somehow not possible (this would be quite rare), you can always collect enough data to use different observations for the model choice and estimation/inferential aspects. In more large-scale or automated modelling situations you may want to perform separation of model choice from data as a matter of course.
D. Have at least some modest level of caution about uncritical acceptance of advice from people who focus on some particular kinds of data and specific kinds of analysis if your circumstances and purposes are distinct from theirs. It's not that they'll be wrong in what they say, but they may tend to emphasize things that are less critical in your situation and brush over aspects you might need to consider, simply because of those differences in circumstances. It's a matter of understanding the context in which their specific focus arises. For one example, the term "OLS" is particularly common among econometricians, and they will tend to have large data sets of observational time series, and they will tend to use their analysis for particular purposes. Much of their advice is excellent in that context - and often to a large extent outside it, perhaps with some caveats here and there. If you have small controlled experiments, say,  some of your considerations may not line up quite so one-to-one with their particular concerns -- e.g. things they might feel free to ignore due to typically having "large samples" you might not have the luxury of having, and things they might rightly worry about (like autocorrelation) might not apply to your situation at all. I have seen experiments with very, very tiny sample sizes and response variables that would clearly be skewed (conditionally on the IVs), and there the properties of inferences may indeed be pretty strongly impacted by distributional assumptions. Many econometricians may never have dealt with a small controlled experiment and so may fail to consider that what works pretty well for what they see every day may not apply quite so precisely to you.
In short, be aware of the circumstances you're in as well as the circumstances of people whose advice you might take; context can matter.
$-$
I may return to add some illustrations or little examples at some point, but I think this is sufficient for now.

* Saying "OLS" could mean you wanted to fit a nonlinear model and minimize SSE to estimate the parameters, and that's fine, but it's less common for people to just call that OLS without some additional qualification, so I assume it's not the case here.

Due to the Central Limit Theorem, technically the residuals do not need to be normally distributed as long as the sample size is large.  In brief, the CLT shows that for many statistics, such as those estimated in a linear regression model (e.g. slopes), the sampling distribution of those statistics will be normally distributed as the sample size gets large, even if the outcome or residuals are not normally distributed.  This allows us to apply standard normal-theory methods for calculating confidence intervals and p-values for the parameter of interest.
But this begs the question of how large does the sample size need to be?  There's really no good rule of thumb here.  Many intro stats classes teach n > 25 or 30, but there are examples of skewed data where N = 50,000 is not enough for the CLT to apply.  You could use the bootstrap to assess whether the bootstrap distribution of the statistic of interest is normally distributed, if yes, this suggests the CLT is applying.
For me, normality of the residuals helps ensure the validity of the statistical inferences of a linear regression model, but it doesn't guarantee the validity: the model could have the wrong functional form (e.g. non-linear or interaction effects may be more appropriate), bias in study design, or unequal variance.
Also note that increasing the sample size does not necessarily help with the equal variance assumption, but heteroscedasticity-robust standard errors are a simple solution.
If you are concerned about the normality assumption being violated, you can instead use bootstrap confidence intervals and pvalues which do not rely on normality.  Or for numeric or ordinal outcomes, you can consider ordinal regression which does not make assumptions regarding the shape of the outcome.
